# I am unable to get $apply inside $watch to work

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, watch

I have a directive for an upload file that communicates with the server and returns a `scope.dbInsertId`. I want to watch this and then update the ng-model with this value. I am unable to get it to work using `$apply`. Here is my code:

```
            scope.$watch('dbInsertId', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue)
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.ngModel = scope.dbInsertId;
                    });
                    console.log("I see a data change!"); 
                    return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, true);
```

Is my code wrong?

Comment: Have you tried scope.$apply

Comment: sorry that was a typo here. I did try `scope.$apply` and that didint work..

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console??

Comment: No error message. I can see the 'I see a data change!' log when the dbInsertId is changed but the ng-model isint getting updated.

Comment: What if you put it outside scope.$apply??

Comment: first - remove IF because watch work only then dbInsertId changes.

Comment: second - remove apply and just put your code in watch function, apply fires on all watch iteration

Comment: Ya I agree with @KoIIIeY..remove that IF condition

Comment: Scratch my last comment. I can only see the  'I see a data change!' message in log when I have `scope.ngModel = scope.dbInsertId;` outside `scope.$apply`. Also the ng-model updates if its outcome `$apply`. However, the reason I am trying to add this apply method is because there is a parent directive that uses this ng-model which is not updating when this scope is updated. I was told that I need to use the apply method since the parent scope is not aware of the change done to this scope.

Comment: show your directive code

Comment: hang-on. I will give you a jsfiddle soon. :)

Comment: try to bind your directive ng-model with parent scope variable

$scope.someVar - in controller
<directive ng-model="someVar">

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of an example on what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Alien_time/dXL4w/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dXL4w/3/

Comment: done :D
Use template instead of $compile

Comment: aha.... that looks promising. I will test it out now and will report back. I am excited!

Comment: And if you want to use parent scope in directive, use: scope: true :)
but I think, all directives should have it's own scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer for your question

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">

        <form name="someForm">
            <div this-directive ng-model="theModel"></div>
            <div>theModel='{{ theModel }}'</div>
        </form>

     </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope,$rootScope,$log) {

    $scope.theModel = '';

    $scope.$watch('theModel',function(newVal,oldVal){
        $log.info('in *MyController* model value changed',newVal,oldVal);
    });
});

app.directive('thisDirective', function($compile, $timeout, $log) {

    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" /><div child-directive ng-model="ngModel"></div>',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        }, // end link
    } // end return

});

app.directive('childDirective', function($compile, $timeout, $log) {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" />',
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        },

    } // end return
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/dXL4w/3](http://jsfiddle.net/dXL4w/3)

Comment: Hi KolleY, I tried changing the scope to isolated and changed `compile` to `template`. The binding works when we type inside the textbox but the scope in parent directive isint updating when child directive's model has changed from $watch. When that happens, the console shows the `I see a data change!` message from the child directive but it is not showing the `*MyController* model value changed` message that is supposed to show as per the controller settings. So this means when scope value of child's directive is dynamically changed, the scope in parent directive is not aware of it. :(

Comment: may be you forget to bind controller variable to first directive?

Comment: Hi KolleY, I finally got it working. In my app, my child directive had a controller which defined the `$scope.dbInsertId`. When I had the `scope.$apply` (or) `scope.$watch` inside the child directive, although the ng-model in the child directive was getting updated, it wasnt updating the scope in the parent directive. But once I added the `$apply` method to the `$scope.dbInsertId` inside the child directive's Controller itself, everytime the `dbInsertId` changed, it then updated the scope for both the child directive as well as the parent directive.

Comment: Finally it worked! phew... I was stuck on this for 2 days. I am happy it works but still wondering why the $apply wasnt binding with the parent scope when I had it in child directive instead of the controller. Too much magic for me.. :) THANK YOU SO MUCH KolleY. I also like my codes a lot better now by using template instead of compile and by having isolated scope for directives. Thanks for guiding me..

Comment: If you can, show your code in fiddle, and I will try to explain what and why work or not

Comment: also, you can use templatePath instead of template

Comment: Thank you @KollleY I tried it in jsfiddle and I works fine there: http://jsfiddle.net/Alien_time/S4k39/3/ Since I was unable to reproduce the error in jsfiddle, I think maybe the problem I was having where the parent directive wasnt updating when child directive was updated when it was $watched was maybe due to the Ajax update that happens in the child directive's controllers and I was using the $apply in the wrong place. Being a Ajax changes, adding the `$apply` method in the controller updated the entire scope so the parent directive was aware of it. This is what I think..

Comment: About JSON requests: angular use promises, just put your data in model and model should change aniwhere.
Example: someAjaxService.query({id: 'blabla'}).$promice.then(function(data){  $scope.model = data; });

It's async request, and data should be shown when it's loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need `scope`:

```
scope.$watch('dbInsertId', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) { // here
    if (newValue)
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.ngModel = scope.dbInsertId;
        });
        console.log("I see a data change!"); 
        return ngModel.$modelValue;
}, true);
```

Comment: I tried adding `scope`. But the parent directive is not aware of the changes done to the child directive.

Comment: Hi Ashesh, Thanks for your input. For some reason, the $apply wasnt working when I had it in my child directive but it worked once I added the $apply method in the child directive's controller that updated the dbInsertId after the Ajax request. Its finally working. Thank you for your help!